# NSData to Custom NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsobject

I'm trying to transfer data between 2 devices using bluetooth.
Device A is holding custom NSObject.
Device B is receiving this custom NSObject as NSData.

What is the best way to decode the received NSData into a custom NSObject ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to implement the `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` methods of your custom object so it knows how to get encoded and decoded into/from an NSData object:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    [coder encodeObject:self.property forKey:@"property"];
    // all other properties
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.property = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property"];
        // all other properties
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then you decode it from NSData to NSObject using:

```
NSObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

The other way around:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:self.filePath];
```

Comment: You should add how to use the `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode the object into `NSData`.